# Is there a way to tell when the result set changes in a MySQL union query?

Tags: mysql, union

Is there a way to either add a separator or know when the results set has changed in a union query? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name >= 'a' AND name < 'g'
UNION  ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name >= 'g' AND name < 'k'
```

While looping through the results, is there a way while looping through the results to know that it is now going through the results from the second query? I was hoping something simple instead of using PHP to grab the first letter to see if the current result is still between and g or if its now between g and k. Can I add a custom separator field that tells me when the results for the next query is now being accessed? Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a computed column to the `UNION` query, and then sort by it:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS position FROM table1 WHERE name >= 'a' AND name < 'g'
UNION  ALL
SELECT *, 2 FROM table1 WHERE name >= 'g' AND name < 'k'
ORDER BY position;
```

This would place the records coming from the `a <= name < g` query first, followed by the records from the `g <= name < k` query second.